# ¿Como utilizo un valor de una clase en otra? en c++

Tags: c++

Tengo este código todo esta separado por ficheros de cabecera (.h) y de implementación (.cpp):

Fitness.h

```
class Fitness
{

  private:

    // Professor's ID
    float _fit;

   public:

    // Inicia los datos del profesor
    Fitness(float fit);

    // Devuelve professor's ID
    inline float GetFit() const { return _fit; }
};
```

Fitness.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Fitness.h"

// Inicializa los datos del fit este es el archivo cpp 
Fitness::Fitness(float fit) : _fit(fit) { }
```

y la parte donde lo utilizo es aquí en una clase llamada `Configuracion`:

Configuracion.h

```
class Configuracion
{

  public:

    //Lectura del Fitness
    hash_map<float, Fitness*> _fit;

  private:

    // Indica que aun no se lee la información
    bool _isEmpty;

  public:

    // Inicia datos
    Configuracion() : _isEmpty(true) { }

    // Libera recursos usados
    ~Configuracion();

    // Analiza datos y guarda datos
    void ParseFile(char* fileName);

    inline Fitness* GetFit(float fit)
    {
      hash_map<float, Fitness*>::iterator it = _fit.find(fit);
      return it != _fit.end() ? (*it).second : NULL;
    }

    inline float GetNFit() const { return (float)_fit.size(); }
    Fitness* ParseFitness(ifstream& file);

    // Remueve caracteres vacios al principio y fin de la cadena
    string& TrimString(string& str);
};
```

Configuracion.cpp

```
Configuracion::~Configuracion()
{
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////
  for (hash_map<float, Fitness*>::iterator it = _fit.begin(); it != _fit.end(); it++)
    delete (*it).second;
}

void Configuracion::ParseFile(char* fileName)
{
  // Limpia objetos previamente analizados
  _fit.clear();
  string line;
  while( input.is_open() && !input.eof() )
  {
    // Leer linea por linea hasta que se obtenga el inicio de un nuevo objeto
    getline( input, line );
    TrimString( line );

    // Lee, analiza y guarda el tipo de objeto 
    if (line.compare("#fit") == 0)
    {
      Fitness* f = ParseFitness(input);

      if (f)
        _fit.insert(pair<float, Fitness*>(f->GetFit(), f));

    }
  }
  input.close();
  _isEmpty = false;
```

Después quiero utilizar el valor de la variable en otro archivo llamado
Horario.cpp

```
float f1 = 0.000000;
//f1 = Configuracion::GetInstance().GetFit();

f1 =(&Configuracion::_fit);

//Horario * f1= &Configuracion::_fit;
if (best->GetFitness() >= 0.45000000)//((&Configuracion::_fit)))//0.4500000 /*_fit/* (&Configuracion::_fit)*/)
{
```

en la linea

```
f1 =(&Configuracion::_fit);
```

tengo el siguiente error:

> Error 2   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'stdext::hash_map,stdext::hash_compare<_Kty,std::less<_Kty>>,std::allocator>> Configuracion:: ' to 'float'

¿Cómo puedo evitarlo para que funcione el trabajar con el valor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si analizamos la llamada en la que se produce el error:

```
float f1 = 0.000000;
f1 =(&Configuracion::_fit);
```

Vemos lo siguiente:

- `f1` es de tipo `float`.
- Intentas asignar a dicho `float` un puntero (por el `&`). Este es el primer error, pero hay más.
- Estás accediendo a `Configuracion` por vía estática y sin embargo `_fit` no está marcada como `static`. 2º error. Los miembros no estáticos de una clase únicamente son accesibles a través de una instancia de la clase. Tu imagínate que hiciese yo algo tal que: `std::cout << Alumno::Nombre`. ¿A qué alumno me estaría refiriendo? tú no sabrías decirlo, yo tampoco y el compilador, obviamente, tampoco... de ahí que esto se trate como un error.
- El miembro `_fit` es de tipo `hash_map<float, Fitness*>`. Salvo que implementes una implementación implícita entre ambos tipos el compilador no va a saber convertir ese `hash_map` en un `float`. 3er error.

¿Posibles soluciones?

La clase `Horario` debería tener acceso a una instancia de tipo `Configuracion`. Como no indicas la cabecera de dicha clase, imaginemos que tiene algo tal que:

```
class Horario
{
  Configuracion m_config;
};
```

En este caso, para acceder a la configuración se podría hacer algo tal que:

```
float f1 = 0.0000;
Fitness* fitness = m_config[f1];
```

Recuerda que en el `hash_map`, la clave es un `float`, luego `f1` únicamente lo puedes utilizar como índice para acceder a un puntero de tipo `Fitness`.

**Importante**: Yo personalmente no utilizaría `float` o `double` como clave de ningún mapa. La razón es que este tipo de números son susceptibles de recibir redondeos. Los números en coma flotante no debería ser comparado **jamás** con el operador de comparación(`if( float1 == float2 )`), y eso es justamente lo que acaba haciendo de una forma o de otra los diferentes mapas para encontrar la clave (da igual que verifique el valor real o un hash). Al hacer esto te puedes encontrar con que al pasar una clave que teóricamente existe, el mapa no te devuelve el objeto esperado.

**Solución 2**

Si resulta que el objeto `Configuracion` debe ser único y accesible para diferentes objetos, puedes convertirlo en un Singleton:

```
class Configuracion
{
  private:
    Configuracion() // No se pueden crear objetos fuera de esta clase
    { }

    Configuracion(const Configuracion&) // Ni tampoco usar el constructor copia
    { }

  public:

    static Configuracion& Instance()
    {
      static Configuracion m_instance;
      return m_instance;
    }
};
```

Y se usaría así:

```
Configuracion::Instance()._fit[5.0] = new Fitness;
```

**Nota adicional**:

No suele ser recomendable tener elementos cuyo nombre empiece por `_`. El motivo es que las constantes y funciones propias del compilador suelen empezar por dicho carácter y esto puede dar lugar a errores extraños al compilar. Si te fijas, verás que yo a las variables internas les he añadido el prefijo `m_` (m de *member*) en vez de `_` a secas.